# If cell is empty, paste, Else, go to next blank cell and paste

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, copy-paste, is-empty

Basically I just need excel to verify if Cell A1 is empty.

If A1 is empty, paste starting in A1.
If A1 is not empty, go down to the next blank cell in Column A, and paste there.

I am receiving an error : Application-defined or object-defined error on the Else part of the code.

```
If IsEmpty("A1") Then
    Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Else
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed two issues. (1) In the first line of code, you are testing whether the text "A1" is empty, not cell A1. So first change it so that the IsEmpty tests the cell A1. (2) As you add entries below A1, you need some method of counting how many rows down to go before pasting. Right now, your code starts at cell A1 and offsets by 1. This will only work once. The sample below counts how many rows are filled in the A column and then offsets by 1 row.

```
If IsEmpty(Range("A1")) Then
    Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Else
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End If
```

Comment: Thank you! It was defining the Range that made the difference. 
I did go ahead and update the Row count for column A, however it seemed to work fine either way since I was telling it to start at cell A1 and Ctrl+Down did the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

### Paste into Next Available Cell in Column

**The Issues**

- Look at your code and imagine that cell `A1` is not empty, but the rest of the cells in column `A` are. Then `Range("A1").End(xlDown)` will 'jump' to the bottom-most cell of column `A`: `A1048576`. You are additionally trying to do `.Offset(1)` which is not possible, hence the error.
- Now again, look at your code and imagine that the range `A1:A5` is not empty, but cell `A6` is. Then `Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)` will 'jump' to cell `A6`. But imagine that cell `A7` is also not empty. Then you will possibly overwrite the value in cell `A7`.

**Introducing a Function (A Quick Fix)**

- You could do:

  ```
  Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = RefFirstAvailableCell(Range("A1"))
  dCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues ' the rest were default values
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  ```

  which uses the following function:

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the First Available Cell in a column,
'               i.e. creates a reference to the cell
'               below the Last Non-Empty Cell in the Column Range
'               spanning from the First Cell of a range ('rg')
'               to the Bottom-Most Cell of the worksheet column.
' Remarks:      If all cells in the Column Range are empty,
'               it creates a reference to the First Cell.
'               If the Bottom-Most Cell of the worksheet column
'               is not empty, it returns 'Nothing'.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefFirstAvailableCell( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Range
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    With rg.Cells(1)
        Dim wsrCount As Long: wsrCount = .Worksheet.Rows.Count
        Dim fRow As Long: fRow = .Row
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(wsrCount - fRow + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then
            Set RefFirstAvailableCell = .Offset
        Else
            Dim lRow As Long: lRow = lCell.Row
            If lRow = wsrCount Then
                Exit Function
            Else
                Set RefFirstAvailableCell = .Offset(lRow - fRow + 1)
            End If
        End If
    End With
    
End Function
```

**Testing the Function**

- Instead of the [`End statement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/end-statement), the function uses the [`Range.Find method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find), which is more reliable. In fact, it 'normally' (think merged cells or similar) only fails if the worksheet is filtered.
- The following procedure illustrates how to copy by assignment, which is 'cleaner' and more efficient (faster) than `PasteSpecial` when copying values only. It also introduces some additional fail-safes (Validate...).
- To utilize it, copy both codes to a standard module (e.g. `Module1`) of a new workbook and make sure it contains `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` (code names). Run the procedure and see what has happened in both worksheets. Repeat the steps a few times and observe the changes in `Sheet1`. Play with it by changing the various constant values in this procedure's code (not the function).

```vb
Sub RefFirstAvailableCellTEST()
    ' Create a reference to the Source Range.
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Sheet2.Range("B2:D5")
    ' Populate the Source Range.
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim n As Long
    For Each sCell In srg.Areas(1).Cells
        n = n + 1
        sCell.Value = n
    Next sCell
    ' Write the number of source rows and columns to variables.
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg.Columns.Count
    ' Create a reference to the Destination Initial First Cell.
    Dim diCell As Range: Set diCell = Sheet1.Range("A2")
    ' Create a reference to the Destination First Available Cell.
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = RefFirstAvailableCell(diCell)
    ' Validate First Available Cell.
    If dCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If dCell.Row > Sheet1.Rows.Count - rCount + 1 Then Exit Sub
    If dCell.Column > Sheet1.Columns.Count - cCount + 1 Then Exit Sub
    ' Create a reference to the Destination Range.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dCell.Resize(rCount, cCount)
    ' Write the values from the Source Range to the Destination Range.
    drg.Value = srg.Value
End Sub
```